# Django/Django Rest Framework DELETE not Allowed for Detail View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-delete

My view is defined with generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.

I put a debugger and it properly enters the view as expected, so I do not think it is a problem with the URL. I am properly providing the resource ID for the resource that is to be deleted.

When I view the response headers, I see:

```
{'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'application/json'), 'vary': ('Vary', 'Accept'), 'allow': ('Allow', 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS')}
```

As you can see, it appears DELETE and even PUT and PATCH are not allowed. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Thanks!

UPDATE to show View:

```
class ItemDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
serializer_class = ItemSerializer
queryset = Item.objects.all()
```

URLS:

```
    path('<int:trans_id>/items/<pk>', views.ItemDetail.as_view(), name='item-detail'),
path('<int:trans_id>/items/', views.ItemList.as_view(), name='item-list'),
```

Here is the Request that is being sent:

```
<WSGIRequest: DELETE '/api/transactions/1/items/1'>
```

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: Updated OP to show view.

Comment: Hm, can you add urls.py also?

Comment: Added the URLS.

Comment: And full error message?:) Do you have any other urls in urls.py?

Comment: Full Error Message: {'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Method "DELETE" not allowed.', code='method_not_allowed')}

Comment: I do have other URLs but they are completely different and don't collide with this one. This app is proprietary in nature and I am masking the domain. As I said in the OP, I properly enter the view when I place a breakpoint inside of the view.

Comment: Can you add the url which you've tried?

Comment: Added the REQUEST to the OP.

Comment: Whats the result if you try with GET method, instead of DELETE?

Comment: The request works, but DELETE is still omitted from the allowable method types:

Comment: {'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'application/json'), 'vary': ('Vary', 'Accept'), 'allow': ('Allow', 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS')}

Comment: While trying with GET method, did you get the `item-list` result ?

Comment: Nope. It goes into the item-detail view, as expected.

Comment: oh.. that's so strange. I tried to reproduce the behavior but failed. Can you share your project?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't considering this is a proprietary project.

Comment: Can you add a re-producing method of your error?

Comment: So I think I deduced that even though it's properly going to my view, it's using "class ListCreateAPIView" behind the scenes, which obviously only has a GET and POST methods. This is pretty weird and I do not understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm an idiot. I was pointing to the correct URL but my testcase was using the wrong VIEW